# How to restrict S3 usage for individual IAM user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs

I am trying to build a service where an IAM User can upload data to s3 and then kick off an ECS task to process the data. I want to be able to limit the user from uploading unlimited amounts of data to s3.

Is there a way to enforce usage limits on s3 (and other AWS services)?

I could not find any S3 policy settings to limit the usage for S3.

Comment: What limit would you like to enforce? 100MB per uploaded file or e.g. 1GB of all uploaded files per single user?

Comment: Why do you wish to limit storage -- is this a cost-saving exercise? Who are your users -- are they staff within your organisation? If so, they presumably have a business need for storing and processing this data. What is the _underlying_ problem you are wanting to solve?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot limit S3 storage space usage with IAM.

If you think about it, you'd need a database to keep track of user-bucket usage statistics to do something like this. IAM is simpler than that, this task is out of the scope of IAM. You'd have to come up with your own solution. For example, you could [use Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) to automatically delete files that are too big.